# Passing dropdown selected value to query inside same form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to pass the value that I select in my dynamic dropdown list, finished_product_code, as the where value in a second query that I have. How can I get the numerical value that I select in the dropdown list to pass to my second query? My dropdown list has multiple values. I only want the value that I select to pass to the second query.

Thank You,

```
<?php 

$query = "SELECT finished_product_code, finished_product_code  FROM 
finished_product_code_descriptions_view";
$aa = 'finished_product_code';

include 'inventory_connect.php'; 

$result = $conn->query($query);

?>

<select name="finished_product_code" style="width:170px; height:21px">;

<option value=""></option>';

<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
echo '<option 
value="'.$row["finished_product_code"].'">'.$row["finished_product_code"].
'</option>';

?>
</select>
<br>

<?php 

$query = "select  finished_product_code from 
finished_product_code_descriptions_view where finished_product_code = $aa";


if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($finished_product_code);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //printf("%s\n", $finished_product_code);
}
$stmt->close();
};
include 'inventory_connect.php';  
echo $aa;
?>
```

Comment: To make this in pure php way you will need to wrap your select in a form where action goes to a php file that handles the selected value in the post / get request and runs your second query.